# YARN does not preempt spark 2.0 tasks

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-2.0

I have a cluster managed by YARN. I have enabled *Fair Scheduling* in `yarn-site.xml` and `fair-scheduler.xml` (see below for details).

According to [Cloudera's blog ariticle on fair scheduling](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/06/untangling-apache-hadoop-yarn-part-4-fair-scheduler-queue-basics/) I expect that if I schedule some tasks to `q1` queue (created on the fly, with default values eg. `weigth=1`) and then schedule some other tasks to `test_queue` (`weight=2`), tasks from `q1` will be preempted (after 1 sec) to balance `test_queue`'s *Fair Share*, but it does not happen.

Instead `q1` uses 70% of cluster resources having *Fair Share* of 33%) and `test_queue` gets 5% of resources having *Fair Share* of 67%.

Did I miss anything?

[image]

Below is my YARN configuration:

```
<!-- yarn-site.xml -->
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

and

```
<!-- fair-scheduler.xml -->
<allocations>
    <queue name="test_queue">
        <weight>2.0</weight>
        <schedulingPolicy>fair</schedulingPolicy>
        <fairSharePreemptionTimeout>1</fairSharePreemptionTimeout>
        <fairSharePreemptionThreshold>1</fairSharePreemptionThreshold>
    </queue>

    <defaultFairSharePreemptionTimeout>1</defaultFairSharePreemptionTimeout>
    <defaultFairSharePreemptionThreshold>1</defaultFairSharePreemptionThreshold>

    <queuePlacementPolicy>
        <rule name="specified"/>
        <rule name="default" queue="test_queue"/>
    </queuePlacementPolicy>
</allocations>
```

I submit Pi calculation jobs from spark examples:

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi  --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 7G --executor-cores 4 /opt/spark2/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar 1000000
```